# Python: run one function until another function finishes

Tags: python, function, background

I have two functions, `draw_ascii_spinner` and `findCluster(companyid)`.

I would like to:

1. Run `findCluster(companyid)` in the backround and while its processing....
2. Run `draw_ascii_spinner` until `findCluster(companyid)` finishes

How do I begin to try to solve for this (Python 2.7)?

Comment: Read about the [threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) and [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) modules.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use threads:

```
import threading, time

def wrapper(func, args, res):
    res.append(func(*args))

res = []
t = threading.Thread(target=wrapper, args=(findcluster, (companyid,), res))
t.start()
while t.is_alive():
    # print next iteration of ASCII spinner
    t.join(0.2)
print res[0]
```

Comment: this works beautifully except for I don't know how to get the output findCluster(companyid) @Sven Marnach

Answer (score 7):

You can use [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html). Or, if `findCluster(companyid)` has sensible stopping points, you can turn it into a generator along with `draw_ascii_spinner`, to do something like this:

```
for tick in findCluster(companyid):
    ascii_spinner.next()
```

Comment: Wow, I never would've thought of that, but that pattern would've greatly simplified some old progress bar code I've done in the past (not Python but same principle applies).  Turn a seemingly multi-threaded problem into a single-threaded one.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you will use Threads. Here is a simplistic approach which assumes, that there are only two threads: 1) the main thread executing a `task`, 2) the spinner thread:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import thread

def spinner():
    while True:
        print '.'
        time.sleep(1)

def task():
    time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread.start_new_thread(spinner, ())
    # as soon as task finishes (and so the program)
    # spinner will be gone as well
    task()
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with threads. FindCluster runs in a separate thread and when done, it can simply signal another thread that is polling for a reply.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do some research on threading, the general form is going to be this

- Create a new thread for findCluster and create some way for the program to know the method is running - simplest in Python is just a global boolean
- Run draw_ascii_spinner in a while loop conditioned on whether it is still running, you'll probably want to have this thread sleep for a short period of time between iterations

Here's a short tutorial in Python -  http://linuxgazette.net/107/pai.html

Answer (score 0):

Run `findCluster()` in a thread (the Threading module makes this very easy), and then `draw_ascii_spinner` until some condition is met.

Instead of using `sleep()` to set the pace of the spinner, you can wait on the thread's `wait()` with a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have a working example? I am new in Python. I have 6 tasks to run in one python program. These 6 tasks should work in coordinations, meaning that one should start when another finishes. I saw the answers , but I couldn't adopted the codes you shared to my program.
I used "time.sleep" but I know that it is not good because I cannot know how much time it takes each time.

```
# Sending commands
for i in range(0,len(cmdList)):             # port Sending commands
cmd = cmdList[i]
cmdFull = convert(cmd)
port.write(cmd.encode('ascii'))

# s = port.read(10)

print(cmd)

# Terminate the command + close serial port

port.write(cmdFull.encode('ascii'))
print('Termination')
port.close()

# time.sleep(1*60)
```